# How I can send customer id from view to controller

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to send customer id from view to controller when I select customer name from dropdown list it will send customer's id  to controller.
here is my code of view file 'customerlifecycleanalytic.php'

```
    <select class="form-control selectpicker customerfilter">
        <option value=''>Select Customer</option>

        <?php
        if (isset($customername)) {
            foreach ($customername as $customernames) {

                echo '<option value="' . $customernames['id'] . '" >' . $customernames['firstname'].'&nbsp'. $customernames['lastname']. '</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

here is my controller code 'Customerlifecyclecontroller'

```
   public function actionCustomerlifecycleanalytic() {

    $customername = Customer::model()->findAll("store_id='" . Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . "'");
    $customerlifecycle = CustomerLifecycle::model()->findAll();
    $this->renderPartial('customerlifecycleanalytic', array( 'customername' => $customername, 'customerlifecycle' => $customerlifecycle), false, true);
}
```

Comment: you mean after submitting ??

Comment: no after click on customer name

Comment: you need jquery then.

Comment: how???can u code me please

Comment: you can check this kevin.  This may help you. Sorry, right now i'm busy with my work. Hope it solves your problem. Keep calm, have patience. Try it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757648/yii2-ajax-post-to-controller-from-dropdownlist-of-view-and-some-action-upon-rec

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..Its working. Hope this will help.

**View:**

```
//view file code. Just add Onchange select attribute like below:

<select onchange="if(this.value) window.location.href='http://yourdomain.com/yourcontroller/youraction/'+this.value" class="form-control selectpicker customerfilter">
<option value=''>Select Customer</option>
<?php
if (isset($customername)) {
    foreach ($customername as $customernames) {
        echo '<option value="' . $customernames['id'] . '" >' . $customernames['firstname'].'&nbsp'. $customernames['lastname']. '</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
// controller file code. just add a variable parameter to hold the id in action method.

public function youaction($id){
    echo "id : ".$id; // customer id 
}
```